# extjs 4 me.model undfined error when creating store

Tags: extjs, model, extjs4, store

I get an error when attempting to create this, very simple, store. I'd like to know what's causing it and how to fix it. Any help appreciated:

me.model is undefined

```
var sortAvailable = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'model_Im_Using',
  storeId:'sortAvailable'

});
```

Below is the code for the model, although I don't think it is a part of the problem

```
Ext.define('APPNAME.model.model_Im_Using', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  modelID: 'BrField',

  fields:[
    {name:'displayName', type:'string'},
    {name:'databaseName', type:'string'}
  ]

});
```

The model is defined in its own file under model/model_Im_using.js I have used this model with some treestores in the same file

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. The store is intended to just has model instances put into it/ taken from it locally. There is no communication with the server side.

Edit: The line the error is on is:

me.setProxy(me.proxy || me.model.getProxy());

Comment: Where and how `model_Im_Using` is declared?

Comment: The model if defined in it's own file. I have succesfully used the model in a few treestores in the same file without any complaint

Comment: @DmitryB I have a model definition

Comment: Could well be this code of yours loads before the model is defined.

Comment: That is possible but I create a treestore right above this, which uses the same model. This part works fine, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: It's really hard to tell without seeing more code; for instance, there could be a typo in the model name. So I guess providing the model definition and the working tree above this could would help.

Comment: The model name is typed the same in the treestore as in this store....The model is included now

Comment: @Izhaki, you say "Could well be this code of yours loads before the model is defined." How would I know? and how can I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 3):

1. If you use namespaces, you have to use namespaces. You can't mix and match. Change `store.model` to `APPNAME.model.model_Im_Using` and you should be ok.
2. what is `model.modelID?`
3. You should follow Sencha [naming conventions](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/class_system).

Here is an example of it working with the correct namespace, and not working without the namespace:

> http://jsfiddle.net/UMXNZ/

```
Ext.define('APPNAME.model.model_Im_Using', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  modelID: 'BrField',

  fields:[
    {name:'displayName', type:'string'},
    {name:'databaseName', type:'string'}
  ]

});


var sortAvailable = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'APPNAME.model.model_Im_Using',
  storeId:'sortAvailable'

});
console.log('ok');

var sortAvailable2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'model_Im_Using',
  storeId:'sortAvailable'

});
console.log('ok');
```

And the error message when using the short name is:

> Store defined with no model. You may have mistyped the model name.

Comment: 3) Wrong. As I said, I referenced the model by the same name in the treestore right above this.

Comment: @BBB  If you change your code to be `model: 'APPNAME.model.model_Im_Using'` it will work. Neil your answer is berating the OP, 1 and 2 are unnecessary

Comment: @Bbb You are wrong. Here it is working with the namespace, and not working without it: http://jsfiddle.net/UMXNZ/

Comment: @Juan. That really isn't the solution, I did it my way in the other store with success. I tried this way, and I get the same error.

Comment: @Neil. I mentioned the model is defined in a different file. Your solution is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: @BBB I guarantee you that's the solution. There is no magic namespace resolution in JS, it's all fake namespacing. You have to use the full model name. If it worked somewhere else, it was because of some other code, not what you've shown here. Being in a different file has nothing to do with it. But you don't seem willing to listen, so good bye!

Comment: @ Juan. The solution you two are implying has been implemented in my file, yet the problem persists.....

Comment: The jsfiddle from Neil shows you how it's supposed to work. You are not showing us everything. I guarantee you there is no way to use a model without providing its full name.

Comment: Logical progression. It's this. Nope, still broken. Oh, then it might be this too, or I don't know. See how your take is different.

Comment: What this shows is that a namespace issue is not the only thing that could cause my error, what I was trying to say all along..

Comment: That's cool. If you inspect your treestore.model you will see that it is in fact not the model that you assigned it. Either way, just use the namespace and this issue is solved. I'm sorry I was snarky, I need more coffee.

Comment: @Neil While that may be a concern it was not causing the problem. Adding the config 'proxy: {type: 'memory'} ' took care of the error

Comment: Did you really downvote my question because your answer didn't solve my problem?

Comment: I'm still having this issue places in my application ,even when using the full name as you suggested. I'm using 4.0.7 any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the config line below to the store took care of the error

```
proxy: {type: 'memory'}
```

Comment: I don't quite get this. If you haven't had your proxy defined, how come the model worked before? Did you have a proxy on the TreeStore, but forgot to have one in this new store/model combination?

Comment: No, the treestore wasn't working. Upon further inspection this may not be the soution. How should I define the proxy if I don't intend for the application to reach a server, but merely hold information??

Answer (score 0):

For my mvc project (with extjs 4.2) I had the same problem but it was not because I mistyped the name of the model.

You have to add also a require at the begining of your controller :

```
    requires:
    [
        'dashboard.model.Column' // > my model
    ],
```

Then you can create a new store programmaticaly in a new function of the controller like this :

```
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
             model:'dashboard.model.Column',
             storeId:'myStoreId'
        });
```

Maybe it can help some people.